# Dividing coins over drawers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I was busy practicing probability questions and formed this question as a derivation of another (perhaps famous?) example. I shall quickly include the original question (in the original question drawers were used, but I will describe it with bags)

There are 3 bags with each 2 coins. bag 1 has 2 gold coins, bag 2 has 2 silver coins, and bag 3 has 1 gold and 1 silver coin. Somebody picks a bag and then a coin at random and it turns out to be gold. What is the probability that the other coin in the bag is also gold. Answer: 2/3.

Now I know how to calculate that, but I was curious to know what would happen with the probability when we put an extra gold coin in bag 3, meaning bag 3 would have 2 gold and 1 silver coins.

I calculated P(G) as 1/3 + 1/3*2/3 = 5/9 and then questioned myself why this isn't equal to 4/7 (the amount of gold out of the total coins).

So I came up with the following question:

We have 4 gold and 3 silver coins in 1 bag, so P(G) = 4/7.
We then randomly divide these coins over 3 bags, given that every bag needs to have at least 1 coin and subsequently let another person choose a bag at random and then 1 coin at random. What is then the probability that the person draws a gold coin? Is this equal to 4/7 or did the probability somehow change? If so, why?

And then why *does* the probability of drawing a gold coin change, when we put all 7 coins in three bags as (2G),(2S),(2G, 1S), even when all three bags have an equal probability of being chosen?

Comment: Interesting question. Part of the question is: how do you divide the coins between the 3 bags? For each coin: pick a random bag of the 3 and assign that coin to that bag? (That won't work, by the way, because you need at least one coin in each bag, so the randomising method needs to be considered carefully.) You do realise what a complicated question you've set up?

Comment: I don't understand the modification when one bag has $3$ coins.  What does it mean for the other coin in the bag to be gold?  Are you asking for the probability of having chosen the bag with two gold coins?

Comment: "why *does* the probability of drawing a gold coin change, when we put all 7 coins in three bags as (2G),(2S),(2G, 1S), even when all three bags have an equal probability of being chosen?" Because the coins are no longer equally likely to be chosen.

Comment: @Prime Mover , haha Yeah I understand that the first question looks like a pesky one :P. However, I would also be happy if somebody could explain only the second part (why the probability does change in that given situation) :)

Comment: Recall that probability is not so simple as "*number of good outcomes divided by number of discernable outcomes.*"  That is only valid when the outcomes are equally likely.  There are two possibilities to playing the lottery, you win or you lose.  You don't win the lottery half of the time however.  Here, your seven outcomes of each different specific coin happen to be equally likely when they were initially together and randomly mixed and randomly distributed to the various bags before someone picking a coin.  The coins are not equally likely to have been chosen in your (2G),(2S),(2G 1S) way

Comment: Momo, oh haha. (I only saw your reply after I wrote my previous comment). Well, that is a very simple answer, but it indeed give me a clarification on the why: If you order the coins 1 to 7, where coins 1,2 are in bag 1. 3,4 are in bag 2 and 5,6,7 are in bag 3. Then for instance, the probability of ending up with coin 1 is bigger than ending up with coin 7. So that is indeed the answer to the second part of the question haha. And thanks @JMoravitz , for the more extensive explanation, while we were writing at the same time haha.

Comment: The first gold goin in the (2G) bag gets picked $\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{2}$ of the time, having had to have picked the correct bag followed by having to pick the correct coin from the bag.  Same with the second gold coin in the first bag, and each of the silver coins in the second bag.  The first gold coin in the (2G 1S) bag however only gets picked $\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}$ of the time.

Comment: @saulspatz , calculating the probability of having chosen the first bag or P(B1 |  G) was indeed the way to solve the original(!) question.  In my variant, I added a coin to the third bag. But the question we are now left with is of a somewhat different nature. You could see the whole part before it as an explanation of how I came up with the question. In the end, the question about dividing 7 coins over 3 bags might be too difficult to quickly solve on this forum. And I am satisfied with the given comments about the rest. But if anybody takes pleasure of solving this question, go ahead! :)

Comment: I don't understand your variant.  What is the event whose probability you seek?  It seems to me that there is a second gold coin in the bag not matter which gold coin you chose first.  That is obviously not what you mean.  What do you mean?